# PHP sleep() Function

Tags: php, function, sleep

I'm trying to insert delays between echo commands and wanted to use the **sleep()** function. Unfortunately, as I understand the sleep() function in PHP delays the whole script. I was wondering if there's a trick around this?

I'm trying to accomplish the following

1. echo a line
2. sleep(2)
3. echo next line
4. sleep(2)

Is there a way to do this with PHP without any JS or something else?

Comment: Is the script run interactive from the CLI or being used to generate a web page?

Comment: Are you talking about delaying the appearance of different lines *in the user's browser*?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use JavaScript.

Comment: PHP works on server so PHP can put to (long, long) sleep only server not browser ;)

Comment: I'm sure someone will correct me if so, but as I recall there is nothing like this. I remember node.js creator Ryan Dahl poking fun at this concept of making your server sleep when you could be doing other things. http://youtu.be/jo_B4LTHi3I?t=7m17s

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "delays between echo commands" or "delays the whole script". Can you give more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: *without any JS*, but you don't want the *whole script* itself to sleep... that will be hard

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is just some javascript:

```
<p id="p"></p>

<script>

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "line1";
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = "line2";
}, 4000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming when you say you don't want to delay the whole script that you're really talking about the output... you don't want to delay the entire output, just the stuff after the sleep.

There's a couple things to keep in mind:

1. IE tends to not display anything until it has received 1k of content. To counter this, you need to start your script by outputting some padding... 1024 spaces, for example. (which will have no effect on the actual HTML display)
2. You need to make sure your content is not being compressed in any way by the web server
3. You need to flush your output buffer after echoing.

That all adds up to something that looks like this:

```
<?php
    // turn off output compression
    @apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);

    // no need to flush after every output call
    ob_implicit_flush(true);

    // some padding for IE
    echo(str_repeat(" ", 1024) . "\n");

    echo("Something here<br />");
    sleep(5);

    echo("Something else<br />");
?>
```

Comment: jcsanyi the part about the output in your reply is exactly what I was thinking. But I think I'm better of letting the whole thing process and do the delays at the client side.